# Division in Multiplicatively Closed Sets of the Natural

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $X\subset \mathbb{N}$ be multiplicatively closed (i.e. $1\in X$, if $x,y\in X$ then $xy\in X$). Write
$$X = \{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$$
where $1=x_1<x_2<x_3<\dots$

Then does there exist an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$
$$\prod_{k=1}^n x_k \quad \mbox{ divides } \quad  \prod_{k=n+1}^{2n} x_k.$$

This is clearly true if $X=\mathbb{N}$ as it will just be $n!|\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$. Further, the statement is not true for all $n$ as if we let
$$X = \{1,3,4,5,\dots\}$$
then when $n=2$ we don't have $a_1a_2=3$ dividing $a_3a_4=20$.

My idea is that if $X$ is not "small" in some sense then for big enough $n$, the set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ should look enough like $\mathbb{N}$ for the statement to be true whereas if $X$ is "small" in some sense then we would have for all $1\leq k \leq n$ there exists an $n<\ell\leq 2n$ such that $a_k|a_\ell$ but I have no idea how to make this rigorous, nor what "small" should mean.

Any proof or idea for how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.